# Generate random numbers and put them into a set

Tags: python

I am trying to generate random numbers and put them into a set. 
I decided to do it using for loop and range function:

```py
for x in range(0, 21, 1):
    print(x)
```

Now I would like to put all the numbers into a set. I am using following code:

```py
x_set = set(str((x)))
print(x_set)
```

Unfortunately the outcome is:

`{'0', '2'}`

I would like to put all numbers into a set (1 - 20). What am I doing wrong?

I am not looking for ready answers. Please show me the way to follow.

Comment: You just add the last nulber `20` that have been splitted in 0 and 2 with the `set` constructor, Use the `add` method in the loop, look the link in comment i've put

Comment: could you please format the code correctly? Are these lines `x_set = set(str((x)))` etc. inside the loop?

Comment: `set(range(21))` will create a list from [0,21) and convert it to a set

Comment: `set(range(21))`

Comment: @Chrispresso Note that `set` takes any iterable, so there is no need to construct an intermediate list. `set(range(21))` will do.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the numbers, you have to do something like:

```
x_set = set()
for x in range(0, 21, 1):
    x_set.add(x)
```

Comment: Or more simply `set(range(21))`